# Как менять фон сайта в зависимости от времени суток?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Как сделать так чтобы фон сайта с 07:00-20:00 фон сайта был белым, a с 20:00-07:00 был темным? И возможно ли это вообще реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$date = new DateTime('NOW');
$hour = $date->format('G');
if ( ($hour > 7) && ($hour < 20) ) {
    // Фон для промежутка 7-20
} else {
    // Фон для промежутка 20-7
}
```